# CSS - overlapping - valid

Tags: css

Is there a valid way to overlap 2 divs.

I have the following, but am unable to make them overlap.

```
#top-border{width:100%; height:60px; background:url(image.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x; float:left; position:relative;}
#header-wrap{width:100%; height:80px; background:none; float:left;}
#header{width:800px; margin:0 auto; height:80px; background:url(taller-image.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x}



<div id="top-border"></div>
<div id="header-wrap">
     <div id="header">links go here.</div>
</div>
```

This essentially gives the effect that the top banner is "popped" out 
but am unable to get them to overlap...

as seen here at the top of the image: http://www.boguscreek.com/images/template.jpg

Answer (score 1):

position:relative;left:-30px  will move element2 30 pixels over element 1

```
<style>
    #div1{
        width:100px; height:100px;
        border:1px solid red;
        float:left;
}

#div2{
    width:100px; height:100px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:-30px;
```

}

```
</style>

<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to get this effect here at the top of the website: http://www.boguscreek.com/images/template.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The only thing similar to overlapping that I see in the image template are the brown bars, but you don't need to use overlapped `<div>`'s for doing that, just the image with the brown bars and the blue mosaic as the background image of `<body>` and put all the content inside of a `<div>`.

Comment: I am trying to avoide huge image files and would rather use smaller images with repeat-x.

Comment: I assumed that, you still can use the method I described with tiled images.